# How can I undo a single keystroke in a textarea/contenteditable in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, clipboard, undo

Chrome, and other web-browsers, seem to coalesce user-made edits (not just insertions!) in HTML's `<textarea>` or `contenteditable` elements into fewer-but-larger undo steps - this is a problem for me because when I type or paste-in a lot of text, and then make a few tiny destructive changes, and then want to undo a single tiny destructive change I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but Chrome will revert the  to how it was before I typed or pasted anything instead of undoing the last keyboard, **the result is that I've just lost my work**.

(This is an issue I face almost daily when posting to StackExchange network sites)

It's also very inconsistent - if I work more slowly then Chrome seems to magically add a *save point*, but if I'm typing-away at my full *wpm* including clipboard operations then Chrome's undo feature is useless to me.

I had a look around `chrome://flags` to see if there were any options for controlling Undo behavior, but no such luck.

Is there a way to force Chrome to *not* coalesce edits and/or to allow for per-keystroke undo/redo?

Answer (score 0):

I see this also on Stack Exchange with Mac on Safari, so I don't know whether this is really browser-dependant or site dependant.
Though Undo takes a large chunk, subsequently applying Redo is more incremental.
It's not perfect, but it does kind of work.

On Mac that's  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  followed by  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  (I assume Windows will be  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  instead of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  )